# How to return nullptr from a lambda function?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have a small lambda function which shall find and return a `QTreeWidgetItem`. But if it does not find the given item, then it shall return a `nullptr`. But if I try to compile it then it gives me an error.

The function:

```
auto takeTopLevelItem = []( QTreeWidget* aTreeWidget, const QString& aText )
{
    const int count = aTreeWidget->topLevelItemCount();
    for ( int index = 0; index < count; ++index )
    {
        auto item = aTreeWidget->topLevelItem( index );
        if ( item->text( 0 ) == aText )
        {
            return aTreeWidget->takeTopLevelItem( index );
        }
    }
    return nullptr; // This causes a compilation error.
};
```

The error:

> Error  1   error C3487: 'nullptr': all return expressions in a lambda must have the same type: previously it was 'QTreeWidgetItem *'   cpp   251

I changed the mentioned line with this and now it compiles:

```
return (QTreeWidgetItem*)( nullptr );
```

but I would like to avoid this syntax. How can I solve this ?

I use `Visual Studio 2012`.

Comment: This looks like a bug in VS2012?

Comment: @Yakk: Why? The error message is quite clear, isn't it?

Comment: @MSalters Hmm.  Strange, I actually thought that so long as the later return types are compatible (implicitly convertible) the first return type, everything was a-ok.

Comment: IIRC the lambda proposal for C++11 was intentionally conservative. Some fairly reasonable extensions were left out just to be safe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add an explicit return type annotation:

```
auto takeTopLevelItem = []( ... ) -> QTreeWidgetItem*
{
    // ...
}
```

That way `nullptr` will be converted to your pointer type properly. You're getting that error because the lambda assumes no conversions should be made, and treats `nullptr_t` as a legitimate alternative return type.

---

As a side note, consider using `(std::)optional` instead. The nullability of pointers can be used to represent a missing return, but it doesn't mean it necessarily should be.

Comment: I disagree with the last point concerning `optional`: most stuff in `Qt` is passed by pointers, and I believe that the result of this lambda is passed somewhere to `Qt`. Also, it is just better to follow their style, even if it may be evil in modern C++.

Comment: @lisyarus Hence *consider*. It doesn't necessarily have to make sense in this particular example, but may be an option for another reader.

Comment: Consider removing the last comment about using `std::optional` instead of returning a nullptr. I don't think it makes your answer any better. The top part is just perfect.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to avoid the syntax, rather than the casting, you could it like this:

```
static_cast<QTreeWidgetItem*>(nullptr);
```

---

I made a small example, on how Bartek's and mine's answer really work:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  int a;
};

auto bla = [] (A* obj, bool flag) -> A* {
  if(flag)
    return obj;
  return nullptr;
//  return static_cast<A*>(nullptr);
};

int main() {
  A obj;
  A* ptr = &obj;
  bool flag = false;
  if( bla(ptr, flag) == nullptr)
    std::cout << "ok\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why *shouldn't* your example compile fine? The parameter struct could be ommited entirely, leaving a lambda which return type is *just* `nullptr_t`.

Comment: You answer is far better @BartekBanachewicz . Deleting mine and giving a +1 to you.

Comment: Your `static_cast` remark was perfectly fine though.

Comment: Hmm, what would you suggest? Editing the answer with only the `static_cast` or deleting it all over? @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: I'd leave just the `static_cast` bit (because the code sample is clearly not relevant here).

Comment: OK @BartekBanachewicz. On second thought I posted another example, that will allow the future reader to play around (and also proves our correctness).

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue with some Smart Pointers, so I found I could do this to avoid the issue:

```
auto myFunc= [](MyClass* class)
{
    MyPointer* pointer = nullptr;
    
    if( class && class->isValid() )
    {
       pointer = class->getPointerInstance()
    }
    
    return pointer;
}
```

Similarly, for shared pointer, just repleace `MyPointer*` by `std::shared_ptr<MyPointer>`.

So your code would looks like:

```
auto takeTopLevelItem = []( QTreeWidget* aTreeWidget, const QString& aText )
{
  QTreeWidgetItem* item = nullptr;
  const int count = aTreeWidget->topLevelItemCount();
  for ( int index = 0; index < count; ++index )
  {
      auto item = aTreeWidget->topLevelItem( index );
      if ( item->text( 0 ) == aText )
      {
          item = aTreeWidget->takeTopLevelItem( index );
          break;
      }
  }
  return item;
};
```